# How to slide a window on reads for a multiline fasta file in C++

Tags: c++, bioinformatics, multiline, fasta, sliding-window

I have a C++ code which reads a fasta file (single line reads) and slides a window of l on the reads to generate the kmers.
Like this:

```
 >NC_000913.3-2320800
 GACGAAGCTGCCGACCAGCGTTTTATGTCAGTGCGGACATCAGCACTGCGTGAACAATTTGCCTGGCTGCGCGAGAACGGTTATCAACCGGTCAGTATTG
```

Now I have another fasta file which has reads more than one line like this:

```
  >LR2957 4054ae1b-13f5-89b1-e7b5-d64cabb8badb NC_000913.3,+strand,4451319-4510860 length=55312 error-free_length=59451 read_identity=74.36%
  TGTAGTCCGTCAAGTTACGTTATTGCTACGTCTATCAGGGAAGTCAACCTGCCTGCAATA
  TGGTAGATAAATCCTATTATGCCGCGAGACAACCCTTGGCTTCCTACACGCGCAGTGGAG
```

This function is:

```
 void Sliding_window_l (const char *ptr, size_t length) 
 {   
    size_t p=0;
   /*find start of a read*/
   for(; ptr[p]!='>' && p<length; p++) {/*noop*/}
   kmer_t kmer = 0;

   while(p<length) {
     //printf("hello second %c\n", ptr[p]);  
     assert(ptr[p]=='>'); /*this will be true*/

     /*skip till newline*/
     for(; p<length && ptr[p]!='\n'; p++) {/*noop*/ }
     p++; /*skip the newline*/

    if(p+LMER_LENGTH > length) break; /*too short a read*/
    kmer = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; ptr[p]!='\n' && i<LMER_LENGTH-1; i++) {
       kmer = lmer_shift(kmer, char_to_el(ptr[p++]));
      //kmer = kmer_cons(kmer, i, char_to_el(ptr[p++]));
    }

  while(p<length && ptr[p]!='\n') {
      kmer = lmer_shift(kmer, char_to_el(ptr[p++]));
      lmer_frequency[kmer]++;

  }
  p++; /*skip the newline*/
 }

}
```

The function runs fine for the single line reads but for multi line reads I get the error like this:

```
 void Sliding_window_l(const char*, size_t): Assertion `ptr[p]=='>'' failed.
```

Can anyone guide me as to how to modify the function so that it runs for multiline reads also. Thank you so much.

Comment: It might be OS specific, and probably file syustem specific. On Linux, consider [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [readahead(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) and [posix_fadvise(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) and  [madvise(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html). Also provide some [mre] in your question

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

```cpp
    while(p < length) {
        // The first time the assertion is true
        assert(ptr[p]=='>');

        for(; p<length && ptr[p]!='\n'; p++) {/*noop*/ }
        p++;
        // Now p points at the beginning of the first line of payload

        // more code...

        while(p < length && ptr[p] != '\n') {
            //...
        }
        // You've finished the first line
        p++; /*skip the newline*/
        // Now p may point to the beginning of another line of the payload
        // The next iteration would start with p pointing NOT to the '>'
    }
```

Did you mean that the assertion shall be done before the loop?

Anyway, if I understood your code correctly, you would lose the kmers that overlap with the end of the previous line and the beginning of the next.

The guides:

1. Simplify your life. Read line-by-line, concatenating the payload to a large string of nucleotides. Whenever you find the end of the input (or you find the next comment that starts with '>') you may start processing the concatenated read.
2. Avoid `const char*`, prefer `std::string`: you are using C++, aren't you?
3. Reformat your code to make it more readable: poor formatting is the root of evil.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I am trying with std::string now as I am using C++. Thank you.